# Angular 16 component export from a shared module not working

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module, angular16

I have created a shared module for my project in Angular 16 and exporting it. Problem is when I am importing this to app.module.ts, it's working as expected. But when I import this to dashboard.module.ts, it's giving following error -

```
Error: src/app/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-navbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-navbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-navbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component DashboardComponent.
```

Code for shared.module.ts is below -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    NavbarComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Code for navbar.component.ts -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {

}
```

Code for dashboard.module.ts -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Code for dashboard.component.ts -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent {

}
```

Code for dashboard.component.html -

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

Code for app.module.ts -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserAuthModule } from './user-auth/user-auth.module';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    UserAuthModule,
    NgbModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I tried to import Navbar component in exactly same way to app.module.ts and used in app.component.html,then it works fine. But it gives error in Dashboard Module.

Comment: Could you show the code for your app.module as well?

Comment: @André Sure. Just now added code for app.module.ts at bottom

Comment: you need to import DashboardModule into app.module

Comment: @SwissaYaakov Already tried importing that to app module. So it works well in app module as expected. But When I import this to Dashboard instead of app, it gives error. My requirement here is to import components of shared module to Dashboard module.

Comment: so you need to import the shared module into app module, its look like your share module not been imported, else use standalone.

Comment: @SwissaYaakov Just now tried this (importing shared module into app module), but still have same issue. Standalone is not a solution in case of my project.

Comment: @SwissaYaakov No, that shouldn't be necessary. When do you get the error? From the moment you visit the page?

Comment: @Pieterjan At the time of compilation

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution and seems it's working. Kindly suggest if this is right approach.

I imported feature module instead of shared module to App module. After that I imported shared module to feature module. And it's working fine now.

App.module -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FeaturedModule } from './featured/featured.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FeaturedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Feature.module -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { FeaturedRoutingModule } from './featured-routing.module';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FeaturedRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
  ]
})
export class FeaturedModule { }
```

Comment: Both approaches have their uses=

<Importing the SharedModule into AppModule>:
Use this module for components, directives, and pipes that are intended to be shared and reused throughout the application. Import it in modules where these shared components are needed globally.

<Importing the FeatureModule into AppModule>:
 Use this module for components, services, and other features that are specific to a certain section or feature of your application. Import it in the AppModule or in other feature modules, depending on where you need to use the components and functionality.